# Induced surface charge and total charge in method of images

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, conductors, method-of-images

In David j Griffith's introduction to electrodynamics section 3.2 example 3.2 author calculate the potential above a grounded sphere such that a charge q is placed above the sphere at a distance
a from the centre. he does this by placing an image charge at a distance b from the centre. Later in the exercise we calculate the induced surface charge density and total induced charge which turns out to be equal to image charge. My question is wether the induced charge is the total charge on the sphere because if so, the induced charge should be equal to zero rather than the image charge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because an object is earthed does not mean it has no net charge.

The field pattern looks something like this.

[image]

You can think of the negative charges on the sphere being held on the sphere by the positive point charge while some positive charges which had been resident on the sphere before it was earthed have move down to earth leaving the sphere with a net negative charge.
Note that the magnitude of negative charge on the sphere is always less than the magnitude of the charge on the positive point charge.